# Setup firewall: ask user to allow new incoming/outgoing traffic?

Tags: internet, security, connection, firewall, ufw

I'm using Ubuntu 12.10 and as I know there is already a firewall on any ubuntu system. It's `ufw` and because I like fancy gui stuff I can use `gufw`, that's very nice.

Now I would like to configure this firewall. I want always a notification if there is some incoming or outgoing traffic. The user should be able to choose `allow once`, `allow always for this` or `refuse`. Can I do this with `gufw`? Or do I need another firewall? What do I have for options? Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Without the use of use of a script similar to [this](http://onehourhacks.blogspot.ca/2011/04/ubuntu-firewall-alerts.html) you cannot get notifications like that easily with gufw. However is an alternative that might work called [FireHOL](http://freecode.com/projects/firehol). Excertpt from the FireHOL website: **FireHOL is secure because it has been designed with the right firewalling concept: deny everything, then allow only what is needed.** I'm not sure if there is any type of allow once setting but besides that it looks pretty good. It is a non gui program, but there doesn't seem to be any alternative program that can do what you want.

Server Fault similar topic [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/7613/is-there-a-personal-firewall-for-linux-ubuntu).

Comment: Well researched answer. Perhaps a list of alternatives to the script and FireHOL from the ServerFault link would be nice...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. From the research that, I've done I haven't seen any alternitaves to FireHOL. :(

Comment: Thank you for the information. This is good to know, but somehow Im disappointed that there are no other options :( The first script is nice, but it´s just a notification - I dont have the choice to allow, deny the in/outgoing address. And FireHOL is, as I understood, outdated.

Comment: Its a 5 year old application, has anyone actually tried this?